# Proof that max value of $n$-bit binary number is $2^n - 1$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, binary

After reading  [this programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771520/why-is-the-maximum-value-of-an-unsigned-n-bit-integer-2n-1-and-not-2n) , I wanted to prove the assertion. I'm wondering whether the below would be considered a complete and clear proof.

***Claim***: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i = 2^n - 1.$

**Base Step**: $\sum_{i=0}^{0} 2^i = 2^0 = 1 = 2^1 - 1.$ (This corresponds to the case of 1 bit.)

**Inductive Step**: Assume $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i = 2^n - 1.$ Then $\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i = (\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i) + 2^n = (2^n - 1) + 2^n.$ We have $(2^n - 1) + 2^n = 2(2^n) - 1 = 2^{n+1} - 1.$

Comment: It looks good to me. I would also comment that the maximum values occurs when all the bits are set to 1, and you are proving that the values is $2^n-1$ in this case.

Comment: Your proof is correct for your claim but you haven't proved your claimed number is indeed the maximum. You would need to show that any number $k>2^n-1$ requires at least $n+1$ bits.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I wasn't sure how much detail was appropriate for this SE as opposed to a programming/CS one.

Comment: FYI - an easier proof is to multiply $(2 -1)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{i+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^I =\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^I= 2^n - 1 $.

Comment: That's the "same" as $(x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = x^n-1$.

Comment: Is it not enough to say that the next biggest number needs $n+1$ bits?

Answer (score 1):

**Taken from comments:**

You have correctly proved that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i = 2^n - 1.$ To complete the proof of the initial claim, you should elaborate on why $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i $ is the greatest number you can make with $n$ bits.